# Open pdf file in new window from variable path name in GSP page

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have a map named `file` I'm receiving from my controller which contains the path and description of a file stored in assets/myfiles/file.pdf the following format:

```
{"filepath": "file.pdf",
"description": "something"}
```

How do I create a link to this pdf in a GSP page I'm rendering?

```
<a href="${resource(dir: 'myfiles', file:' ${file[filename])' }" target="_blank">${file[description]}</a>
```

I tried the above but it doesn't open the pdf but just another cloned tab of the app

Comment: Resource's is for application resources pre assets on grails 2. You will need to look up how assets loads images and possibly configure the new folder in assets configuration.  Most importantly since this is in assets folder I presume in app what happens when you reinstall war do you need to persist files through out app history like.  If so method is flawed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Controller Method And Write A Connection To Download Your File.

**GSP:**
Write the Button And Create A link To this Controller Action In Your GSP like below.

```
<g:link class="btn btn-info btn-sm" 
      action="downloadMyFile" resource="${instance}" 
                           target="_blank">DOWNLOAD FILE</g:link>
```

**Controller:**

```
        // This is Used To Open PDF File. 
        def downloadMyFile(){
            def file = new File("download/path/to/your/file")
            response.setContentType("application/pdf")
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${file.getName()}")
            response.outputStream << file.newInputStream()     
        }
```

[OR]

```
        // This is Simply Download Your File.  
        def downloadFile(){
             def file = new File("Path/to/your/File")
             response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
             response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${file.getName()}")
             response.outputStream << file.newInputStream()  
        }
```

Note:

resource        : You can pass Instance to your download action.
 target="_blank" : Open/Download File In New Tab.
 action          : Action name that is defined in Controller.