# Downloading a file in grails using JavaRx / rx-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, rx-java, reactivex

I am trying to download a file in Grails 3.2.1. I have a org.bson.types.Binary Type called "file" saved in mongo-db. The size of the files stored are in kb so no need for GridFS.

I can access the byte[] using the getData() helper that org.bson.types.Binary provides. Using standard mongo-db drivers I can achieve this with the following:-

```
class DownloadController {

  def stream() {
     def fileDB = FileDB.get(params.id)
     if(fileDB) {
        response.setContentType(fileDB.contentType)
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",  "filename=${fileDB.id}.wav")
        response.outputStream << fileDB.file.getData()
     } else {
        //handle error
     }
  }


}
```

With Mongo Rx Drivers and more specifically RxJava. How do I download a file from a Observer subscribe? Grails provides a RxController which provides helpers for rx.render and rx.respond, however I cannot get my head around the response. TBH, I am trying to get my head around ReactiveX! This is what I have so far:-

```
class DownloadController implements RxController {

   def stream() {

        FileDB.get((Serializable) params.id).subscribe({ fileDB fileDB->
            //How do I handle this??
            response.setContentType(fileDB.contentType)
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${fileDB.id}.wav")
            response.outputStream << fileDB.file.getData()
        })

   }

}
```

Any advice would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Refer this question : [download File Attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-from-variable-path-name-in-gsp-page/39542861#39542861)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. It uses the render method (see http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/grails-goodness-render-binary-output.html). If it doesn't please report an issue:

```
def stream() {

    FileDB.get((Serializable) params.id).subscribe({ fileDB fileDB->
        rx.render(fileName:"${fileDB.id}.wav", 
                  file:fileDB.file.getData(),
                  contentType:fileDB.contentType)
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following (snippets will be in java/groovy "pseudocode")
`

```
    Observable<Response> response = ...;
    Observable<FileDB> fileDb = FileDB.get(params.id);
    Observable<Response> processedResponse = response.zipWith(
            fileDb.filter(content != null)
               .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(new RuntimeException())),
            (resp, file) -> {
                 resp.setContentType(file.contentType)
                 resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${fileDB.id}.wav")
                 resp.outputStream << fileDB.file.getData()      

                 return resp;
            });

 processedResponse
   .subscribeOn(Shedulers.io())
   .subscribe(response -> {/*save response*/}, error -> {/*handle error*/});
```

The idea is to zip `Response` with `FileDB` observable, but emit error if file is null. In case you get `Response` synchronously, wrap it with `Observable.just(resp)`