# Grails downloading pdf file from REST webservice endpoint

Tags: java, pdf, grails

I am trying to write a feature where I call a REST endpoint, which gives me back a rest response with `content-type: application/pdf`, which looks something like this:

`%PDF-1.4`
`%����`
`4304 0 obj`

`4330 0 obj` 
`<</C 1636/Filter/FlateDecode/I 1658/Length 1188/S 1431/T 1552>>stream`
`h�bb�����������؀���cP�a\h�b�q���K��f���X���%�s<�o��`
`��u.{��b�'�6��&����:�mV�ꛒ��妴�قU�"��I�\T�.��l��`

when I try to get the class of this body, it tells me that it's a string.

this is what my controller looks like...

```
def download(){

     try{

    def documentContent = //rest response//

  if(documentContents){
    String body = documentContents.body
    byte[] data = body.getBytes("UTF-8")

    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    response.setContentLength(data.length)
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=test.pdf")

     response.outputStream << data
     response.outputStream.flush()
     response.outputStream.close()
     return
    }
  }

catch(Exception e){

   println("abc")
  }

render status: 204
```

From my controller, I get a pdf file with the pages, but it's all blank.

Comment: Where does the PDF content come from

Comment: Just look at this question you may get any idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-from-variable-path-name-in-gsp-page/39542861#39542861

Comment: The PDF content is coming from a web service endpoint in one of the servers. I checked the code on the back end and it doesn't seem to be base64 encoded either. It is simply just sending the bytes.

Comment: As far as I know, the encoding for the response is UTF-8 and it is not base_64 encoded. However when I curl the file, it works fine. I am not sure what curl actually does to the file in terms of conversions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the adjusted code..but I am still getting the same result.

```
def generatePDF(){

 String body = documentContents.responseEntity.body
 ByteArrayOutputStream docStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream() 
 docStream.write(body.bytes) /* Write bytes into byte array*/
 response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=test.pdf")
 response.setContentType("application/pdf")
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
 response.contentLength = docStream.size()
 response.outputStream << docStream.toByteArray()
 response.outputStream.flush()
 response.outputStream.close()
}
```

Comment: forgot a  )  after filename=test.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing a critical difference right now, but this is working for me...

```
def generatePdf(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream docStream = /*call that generates pdf data*/
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 'inline; filename=print.pdf')
    response.setContentType('applicaton/pdf')
    response.contentLength = docStream.size()
    response.outputStream << docStream.toByteArray()
}
```

To be explicit about why this works: Note the lack of response.setCharacterEncoding(). It would only be appropriate to use response.setCharacterEncoding() if the response was going to be some flavor of plaintext. In your case, the response is a PDF, a binary file, and not Text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
// assuming you have already retrieved the file 
// you can also use new File(path) instead of data
render(file: data, fileName: "fileName.pdf", contentType: "application/pdf")
```

FYI: This works for Grails 3.x. It is not tested with older version.

Comment: I actually downloaded the file to my local drive, and tried streaming the file through Grails to the website, this shows the PDF file in its entirety. This lead me to think that it might actually be an encoding problem, even though in the response, the encoding is UTF-8 and in my response header I also set it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Using a REST service providing a stream of bytes of PDF file, you may base the receiving on an inputstream and so you can take advantage of the powerful Apache IOUtils library.
See below the piece of code of a controller (tested on GRAILS3):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def content=urlrestservicestring.toURL().getBytes()
if (!content) throw new Exception("Pdf not available")
def docStream   = new ByteArrayInputStream(content)
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=thenameyouwant.pdf")
response.setContentType('multipart/form-data')
IOUtils.copy(docStream,response.outputStream)
response.outputStream.flush()
response.outputStream.close()
```