# How can I access a local file from my code in a web app

Tags: file, tomcat, grails, web-deployment, filenotfoundexception

I have this line of code that works well on my local machine, but when I deploy to tomcat I get java.io.FileNotFoundException. Here's the code:

```
def file = new File("data/TransactionTypes.xml") ;
```

Comment: Try using absolute path.

Comment: where is the data folder placed ?

Comment: Go through this question it may help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-from-variable-path-name-in-gsp-page/39542861#39542861)