# Grails: Render pdf from external location

Tags: pdf, grails

I currently have this in my grails view to open a pdf file in a new window:

```
<a href="${resource(dir: 'userGuides', file: file.getValue())}" target="_blank">   ${file.getValue()}</a><br/><br/>
```

where `file.getValue()` is the name of the file with extension.
This defaults to the path of grails-app/assets/userGuides. I want to change this so that it opens the file from a local destination, for example C:/Users/user1/userGuides/

How would I change this ?

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-from-variable-path-name-in-gsp-page/39542861#39542861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in grails 2.x, you can configure a target directory in Config.groovy

For instance

grails.datapath.userguides = "C:/Users/user1/userGuides/"

if you want to configure this depending the environment you can do like this :

```
development {
    grails.datapath.userguides = "C:/Users/user1/userGuides/"
}
test {
    grails.datapath.userguides = "C:/anotherDirectory/userGuides/"
}
production {
    grails.datapath.userguides = "/var/www/${appName}/userGuides/"
}
```

Then define a controller to access your files, for example a DocumentsController with this action

```
def downloadUserGuide()
{
    ... // code to get your entity file that you use in your example to do
    ... // file.getValue()

    String path = grailsApplication.config.grails.datapath.userguides
    String label = ... // If you want to display another file name

    render(contentType: "application/pdf", file: new File(path + file.getValue()), fileName: label)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!