# How to view a doc/pdf file in grails application?

Tags: grails, gsp

I am a grails beginner, and finding a way to view the doc/pdf files in the view. I tried embedding the file but got no output for it. How can i view the file?

Comment: View means to preview the pdf file in your context?

Comment: Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536317/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-from-variable-path-name-in-gsp-page/39542861#39542861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't just want to link to some other file on your server (if you do, Rahul's answer is perfectly fine) then you may want to consider something like this in a controller:

```
def retrieveFile() {
    File fileToReturn = new File("${params.filePath}")
    String filename = "whatever your filename is"
    byteOutput = fileToReturn.readBytes()
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${filename}\"");
    outputStream << byteOutput
}
```

Then link to that (g.createLink or whatever) with the appropriate file path.

Comment: Note that I wouldn't expose this exactly this way because then a person can download whatever they want.  You should carefully control what file path you allow access to.

Comment: can i pass this to the view and put in the object tag?

Comment: @Judithkaushik  This code is what the data url in you object tag should map to, as it will result in a stream of the PDF (or, as Daniel points out, any file specified in params.filePath.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<embed>` or `<object>`tag in your `gsp` file

**`<embed>` tag Example:**

```
<embed src="http://example.com/your-file.pdf" width="800" height="500" type='application/pdf'>
```

**`<object>` tag Example:**

```
<object width="800" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="http://example.com/your-file.pdf">
    <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
```

Above code tested and working with chrome and Firefox.

Basically there are many solutions, where you can you third party plugins and or using `<iframe>`

Thanks, Hope it helps you

Comment: i tried it, but it was displaying empty. o ly the object space was occupied

Comment: have you replaced `http://example.com/your-file.pdf` with valid pdf URL? Because i have tested it in my grails app

Comment: yes. i got a solution though. Thank you for the help